# Diamagnetism Experiment

Tags: magnetic-fields

I need to do a diamagnetism experiment but I don't have quite a knowledge about magnetism.

First, I don't know which parameter I need to look to chose right neodymium magnets for diamagnetic effect. Surface field, pull force, Shape etc.
For example, I want to create a surface 3 cm X 3 cm. What is the best way to do it for maximize diamagnetic force. Like 5mm X 5mm X 5 mm (0.5cm X 0.5 cm X0.5cm) cubes or 15mm X 15mm X 5mm bloks? And in what thickness 5mm or 10 mm change the diamagnetic force? I read that most powerful sides of a magnetic field are corners at block magnets, is that mean if use smaller magnets that makes the magnetic field and diamagnetic force stronger?

Comment: If you are working with magnets then they are not diamagnetic materials. How then can you look for a diamagnetic force. Do you mean the diamagnetic part of force that every material have due to the orbital motion?

Comment: @SAKhan, I guess we are talking about the force on a diamagnet in the field of a permanent magnet.

Answer (score 0):

The closer the opposite poles in a magnet the smaller typically the field. So bigger cubes will result in a bigger field. 
If I remember my physics classes at University correctly, the diamagnetism experiment used some organic material from a tree (porous and very light) and a simple copper coil with a few hundreds of windings. Note that to get repulsion you need a strong field and a strong field gradient at the same time, but in the classroom experiment a coil providing something in the range of 100 mT seemed to be OK.

Final note: Please be careful with larger neodymium magnets. The can apply quite strong forces. Moreover, they are brittle and if they smash, small peaces are dangerous for your eyes.